# YII How to redirect my own page?

Tags: php, redirect, yii

I need to redirect to another my own page after saving the data.To do that I duplicate create.php and _from.php (create_1.php and _from_1.php). But when I redirect to it yii give error 404

```
//AssimentController.php
 if($this->saveed($data1,$studentid,$modelcrite,$model))
{
     Yii::app()->session['model']=$model;
     $this->actionCreate_1();
}

  public function actionCreate_1()
{
   $model=new Assiment;
   $modelcrite=new AssimentMarks;
   $this->redirect(array('create_1'),
                        array('model'=>$model,'modelcrite'=>$modelcrite,));
}
```

//in accessRules() function

```
array('allow',  // allow all users to perform 'index' and 'view' actions
                'actions'=>array('index','view','Create_1'),
                'users'=>array('*'),
            ),
array('allow', // allow authenticated user to perform 'create' and 'update' actions
                'actions'=>array('create','update','Create_1'),
                'users'=>array($user->isTeacher())
            ), 
array('allow', // allow admin user to perform 'admin' and 'delete' actions
                'actions'=>array('admin','delete','create','Create_1'),
                'users'=>array($user->isAdmin())
            ),
```

can any one tell me how to solve this problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line

```
public function actionscreate_1()
```

should read

```
 public function actionCreate_1()
```